# regular and slowly varying functions examples $e^{\log(x)}$, $e^{\lfloor \log(x) \rfloor}$, $2 + \sin(x)$ and $e^{(\log(x))^\beta}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, slowly-varying-functions

A function $f$ is called *regular varying* with level $\alpha$ if for any $\lambda > 0$ it holds

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(\lambda x)}{f(x)} = \lambda ^\alpha$.

A regular varying function with level $\alpha = 0$ is called *slowly varying*.

Given is following task:

Which of the following functions are regular varying?

$f_1(x) = e^{\log(x)}$

$f_2(x) = e^{\lfloor \log(x) \rfloor}$

Which of the following functions are slowly varying?

$f_3(x) = 2 + \sin(x)$

$f_4(x) = e^{(\log(x))^\beta}$, $\beta \in \mathbb R$

The first function is easy since I am interested in the limes for $x \rightarrow \infty$, I can use that for $x>0$ it holds that $f_1(x) = e^{\log(x)} = x$ and thus $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f_1(\lambda x)}{f_1(x)} = \frac{\lambda x}{x} = \lambda$, so $f_1$ is regular varying with level $\alpha = 1$.

Do you have some hints for the other functions?

Comment: Taking $\lambda = e^{1/2}$ for $f_2$ then when $x=e^{n}$ with $n$ an integer, then you have $f_2(\lambda x)=f_2(x)$ so you'd need $\alpha=1.$ But when $x=e^{n+1/2}$ you have $f_2(x)=x,f_2(\lambda x)=ex$ so you have $\limsup f_2(\lambda x)/f_2(x)=\lambda^2$ and $\liminf f_2(\lambda x)/f_2(x) = 1.$ This means the limit can't exist.

Answer (score 1):

For $f_{2}(x)$, I would use the estimate
$$
\log(x) - 1 \leq \lfloor \log(x) \rfloor \leq \log(x),
$$
so
$$
e^{-1} x \leq f_{2}(x) \leq x,
$$
and
$$
\log(\lambda) + \log(x) - 1 \leq \lfloor \log(x) \rfloor \leq \log(\lambda) + \log(x),
$$
so
$$
e^{-1} \lambda x \leq f_{2}(\lambda x) \leq \lambda x.
$$

As for $f_3(x) = 2 + \sin(x)$, let
$$\lambda = {1 \over 2}.$$
What is the behavior of
$$
{f_{2}(\lambda x) \over f_{2}(x)}?
$$
(Specifically, what are the minima and maxima?)

Comment: You can't really use $g_3(x)=\sin x$ since you'd have to divide by zero.

Comment: I dont know how to use the inequalities, the deliver me
$\frac{f_2(\lambda x)}{f_2(x)} \leq \frac{\lambda x}{f_2(x)} \leq \frac{\lambda x}{e^{-1} x} = e \lambda$
and
$\frac{f_2(\lambda x)}{f_2(x)} \geq \frac{e^{-1} \lambda x}{f_2(x)} \geq \frac{e^{-1} \lambda x}{x} = e^{-1} \lambda$.
The limit for $x \rightarrow \infty$ would have no effect since the inequalities are independent from $x$. I don't see where this is proves or disproves varying function.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thanks.  Edited.